# What's the syntax when using a formula instead of a value as the logical expression?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

My SWITCH function returns false when the logical expression is a formula in a cell.

Here's what works as expected:

=SWITCH(B3,12,"DEC","NONE")

output is **DEC**
where B3 contains the value **12**

However, if B3 contains the formula:
**=left(A3,2)**

and A3 contains the value **12345**
then B3 is correctly displaying the value **12**
but the SWITCH function returns **NONE**.

I've tried this:

=SWITCH(LEFT(A3,2),12,"DEC","NONE")

but that also returns **NONE**.

So, how do I get the function to recognize the value of the cell with the formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must understand that each piece of data has a data type: string, number or Boolean. Even if those look or seem the same when you see them, they are not.

So the number 12 is not the same as the string "12"; and computers know the difference. (If you're interested, Boolean values are `TRUE` and `FALSE`, which are not the same as the strings "TRUE" and "FALSE.")

Functions like `LEFT` are string functions. Even if the source data is a number, `LEFT` (etc.) force the output to be a string.

You have a couple of choices with your formula then:

1.) `=SWITCH(LEFT(A3,2),"12","DEC","NONE")`

2.) `=SWITCH(LEFT(A3,2)*1,12,"DEC","NONE")`

Here, multiplying the string by 1 with `*1` forces it back to being a number, just as applying `LEFT` forced the source data to be a string.

*However*, if A3 might ever result in some string that cannot be coerced to a number, then option #2 here will result in an error; so you'd want to use option #1 in that case.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, Erik. Thank you!

Comment: If you would, please take a moment to mark the solution post as "Best Answer." This let's the volunteer community here know at a glance from the main listings page which posts have already been addressed successfully; and it allows future site visitors to more easily find the answer that match their own needs and search terms. Thanks.